# Issue with negative margin on Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, html, margin

I have tried every possible resolution on this thing. No luck still, I am having a problem with negative margins on IE and FF.

I just need to set the negative margin on an item but it only affects the element and leaves its children behind.

Check out the effect here. http://s-4-k.co.uk/s4k2/

Can someone help me out please. I am desperate.

Comment: Where is the problem? Which element, id, or class?

Comment: The problem is with element id slide-info. When I add the negative margin. It looks great on Other browsers, chrome, opera etc, however on ie and ff, the background is the parent div is the only div affected. Child divs are left behind.

Comment: Have you tried using relative positioning? `style="position: relative; top:-262px;"`

Comment: Yes I have, I have gone through previous answers on SO

Comment: Sorry, but your CSS is a mess. I'd get diarrhea if I had to troubleshoot that. You've got way too much in-line styling and way too many stylesheets.

Comment: It works but leaves a fat space underneath the element which I have no idea how to get rid off.

Comment: You might try getting your HTML and CSS to both validate using the W3C validation websites. It's a great way to resolve problems and learn more about writing clean, high-quality code.

Comment: My HTML is valid except for minor warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use float none for parent div it will make the behaviour common on all browsers and then set margin in negative according to your needs.

```
.row-fluid .span12 { float: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `bottom: -20px // replace this value with yours` did the trick for me.